# RegEx for matching URLs with video IDs

Tags: ios, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to make an iOS shortcut that will makes me open all the websites videos links at once in new tabs so for that I need a RegEx for it.

Here is how the video links on this website look like:

```
https://m.worldstarhiphop.com/apple/video.php?v=wshhn5icmk9cKSyh9A17    
https://m.worldstarhiphop.com/apple/video.php?v=wshhc8Ew271C2BZE0l31
```

I have this so far:

```
^(?!image$).*(worldstarhiphop.com/apple/video)
```

Because I don’t want the shortcut to open all images links but only video links.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Can we see the code for your previous attempt(s)?

Comment: I only have this so far because I don’t want the shortcut to open images links but only video links:

Comment: I can’t paste what I have

Comment: Please add all relevant code into the body of the question, not the comment section.

Comment: Yeah I added it to the post

Comment: Try `^(?!.*image).*worldstarhiphop\.com/apple/video`

Comment: Still not working sadly

Comment: Perhaps `^(?!.*image).*?worldstarhiphop\.com/.*?/video\.php\?.*`

Comment: Still not working. I think the issue is with the website

Answer (score 1):

I have added multiple capturing groups to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/byqUeu/1) to be easy to modify/change and understand:

```
^((https?:\/\/.*)(worldstarhiphop.com)((\/apple\/video.php\?v=)|\/videos\/video.php\?v=)([A-Za-z0-9]{20}))
```

I did not close the right side using `$`, which you can do so, if you might want to.

The URLs you are wishing to match are in two mobile and web versions, which I have added both with various protocols, just in case. If it is unnecessary, you may remove it.

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

The graph visualize how it works and you might want to test other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Basic Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet returns runtime of a 1-million times `for` loop for performance.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = 'https://m.worldstarhiphop.com/apple/video.php?v=wshhc8Ew271C2BZE0l31';
 const regex = /^((https?:\/\/.*)(worldstarhiphop.com)((\/apple\/video.php\?v=)|\/videos\/video.php\?v=)([A-Za-z0-9]{20}))/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "\nGroup #1: $1\nGroup #2: $2 \nGroup #3: $3 \nGroup #4: $4\nGroup #6: $6 \n");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: Thanks again For the help

Comment: it helps a bit but when i run it on the website none of the links are showing up... I feel like there is something on the website that prevents the regex to work properly

Comment: yup looks like it